# Yarn global add <package> gives error "couldn't find package on npm registry"

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm new to yarn and when trying to install bower or gulp or any other packages global using the following command

```
yarn global add <package>
```

I get following error

[image]

- I have yarn path setup in my .bash_profile as
- yarn version 1.0.1
- node version v8.4.0

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This error was resloved by running

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

npm registry was missing in config file

Comment: it fixed my issue ... mark it as answer if you want

Answer (score 3):

If you tried everything like registry setup, clearing cache and other commands for npm and yarn and your issue is not solved then try a simple approach by deleting lock files from your folder and run "yarn install" again.